# Entity Framework not releasing memory?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, memory-leaks

I'm dealing with my C# program memory usage I set up a memory control between the start and the end of my app to spot memory leaks. I got warning when using Entity Framework 6 with Firebird:

```
var m = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024 / 1024; // 2MB

using (Entities context = new Entities(ConnectionString))
{
     m = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024 / 1024; //2MB
     context.MYTABLE.FirstOrDefault();
     m = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024 / 1024; // 5MB
}

m = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / 1024 / 1024; // 5MB ??
```

By commenting out the `context.MYTABLE` line, memory will remain at 2MB.

I know everything will be disposed when the application will end, but I would like to detect memory leaks on my objects and this EF problem prevent that.

Is there a way to dispose this extra memory used by EF?

Could this problem be caused by the Firebird EF driver?

Tia

Comment: It makes no much sense to measure the memory used by a small block of code in a world where you don't control memory allocation and deallocation in fine details. EF keeps things in memory to speed up things and you better don't try to play with that

Comment: Are you running `Debug` or `Release` build?

Comment: Did you try measuring the same code second, third etc. time? Because the very first time EF builds and caches the metadata model.

Comment: @mjwills, in debug mode

Comment: @ivan, I tried and the memory remains at 5MB. So yes, the metadata is cached. The question is where is it cached and how to clear it?

Comment: It's cached statically once per `DbContext` type and cannot be released (as usual with `static` variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to dispose this extra memory used by EF?

No - there is no way to *release* that extra memory in a **guaranteed** way.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `GetTotalMemory(true)` states:

> **Remarks**
>   If the forceFullCollection parameter is true, this method
>   waits a short interval before returning while the system collects
>   garbage and finalizes objects. The duration of the interval is an
>   internally specified limit determined by the number of garbage
>   collection cycles completed and the change in the amount of memory
>   recovered between cycles. The garbage collector does not guarantee
>   that all inaccessible memory is collected.

Note in particular the last sentence:

> The garbage collector does not guarantee
>   that all inaccessible memory is collected.

*On top of this, Entity Framework (and / or Firebird driver) is likely keeping some information cached in RAM for the lifetime of the application. And some of that will likely never be GCed.*

Comment: Thanks. I included the extra memory into my memory leaks detection.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason for the garbage collector to run after you exit the `using` block (using only guarantees that the `Dispose` method of `context` will be called). You can force a garbage collection using `GC.Collect()`.

More generally, entities that are loaded using EF will generally live as long as the context they are associated with, unless you manually remove them from the context.

I cannot speak to a memory leak in the Firebird driver for EF, but what you are seeing is expected begaviour.

Comment: `GetTotalMemory(true)` is supposed to do a `GC.Collect`. Explicitly adding the collect does not change anything.